# the number of maximum allowed connections have been reached or exceeded for Topic:"TestTopic" azure service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Last night i faced following issue after deploying my site to windows azure. i am using service bus topics

### the number of maximum allowed connections have been reached or exceeded for Topic testTopic:Topic:testTopic2. Number of active connections: 100, Maximum allowed connections: 100..TrackingId:de48e192-e8a8-401c-aeae-731c8630fb06_H3_G3_B6,TimeStamp:2/20/2013

I have one topic testTopic and 3 subscriptions to do different jobs. i am not using testtopic2 its empty topic.

any idea guys?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you have more than 100 concurrent processes connected to the Topic. Each time your create a MessagingFactory or Topic/SubscriptionClient it will be a connection to the Topic. If you can share any code snippets then we can confirm, but looks like there is some loop that may just be creating more and more client connections (maybe 1 per message)?